# How can I get query string params after inertia replace?

Tags: inertiajs

I have a function to get query string params:

```
extractQuery() {
   let uri = window.location.href.split('?');
   if (uri.length == 2)
   {
      this.$query = qs.parse(uri[1]);
   }
   console.log(this.$query)
}
```

and it works, fine, but if I replace query string using:

```
Inertia.replace((this as any).route('index', {new: 'true'}))
```

And call function again, I do not see "new" param, how can I get all the params after a replace?

Thanks!

Comment: did you found a solution?

Comment: Push route by myself on history